# Atmel AT86RF233 read phase measurement

Tags: atmel, atxmega

I've started working with the [AT86RF233](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8351-MCU_Wireless-AT86RF233_Datasheet.pdf) a few weeks ago and found the Ranging Toolbox (RTB) package quite impressive. It's the first time I'm using wireless modules, so I wanted to see if I could use the Phase Difference Measurement Unit (PMU) for another usage than ranging.

My problem is that I can't get the PMU value. Even trying just to print the value during a ranging of the original RTB firmware doesn't work. I noticed I had to set the `pmu_en` flag, but this didn't change much. I just get values between 0 and 20 instead of the expected 0 to 255. When `pmu_if_inverse` enabled I just get 0.

Has anyone experienced the same problem? Or is there some working code using the PMU I could read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically while being in the advanced RX-Mode (RX_AACK_ON) it is not possible to measure the pmu. You have to be in RX_ON